# i want to place my module inside catalog menu in admin panel?

Tags: magento-1.9

How to add my module `Matrid_Freemanager` inside catalog menu with manage item submenu . my file  `web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Web>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Company_Web>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <web>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Company_Web</module>
                    <frontName>web</frontName>
                </args>
            </web>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <web>
                    <file>web.xml</file>
                </web>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <admin>
        <routers>
   <web>
    <use>admin</use>
    <args>
     <module>Company_Web</module>
     <frontName>web</frontName>
    </args>
   </web>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
<menu>

   <web module="web">
        <title>Matrid_Feedmanager</title>
            <sort_order>29</sort_order>               
                <children>
                        <items module="web">
                            <title>Manage Items</title>
                                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                            <action>web/adminhtml_web</action>    
                        </items>
                </children>
    </web>

 </menu>
  <acl>
   <resources>
    <all>
     <title>Allow Everything</title>
    </all>
    <admin>
     <children>
      <Company_Web>
       <title>Web Module</title>
       <sort_order>10</sort_order>
      </Company_Web>
     </children>
    </admin>
   </resources>
  </acl>
  <layout>
   <updates>
    <web>
     <file>web.xml</file>
    </web>
   </updates>
  </layout>
    </adminhtml>   
    <global>
        <models>
            <web>
                <class>Company_Web_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>web_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </web>
            <web_mysql4>
                <class>Company_Web_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <web>
                        <table>web</table>
                    </web>
                </entities>
            </web_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <web_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Company_Web</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </web_setup>
            <web_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </web_write>
            <web_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </web_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <web>
                <class>Company_Web_Block</class>
            </web>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <web>
                <class>Company_Web_Helper</class>
            </web>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it properly, create `adminhtml.xml` in : `app/code/local/Matrid/Freemanager/etc/adminhtml.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <catalog translate="title" module="catalog">
             <children>
                <items module="web" translate="title">
                    <title>Manage Items</title>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    <action>web/adminhtml_web</action>    
                </items>
            </children>
        </catalog>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        //put also your acl here instead in config.xml like native Magento modules
    </acl>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing you menu code in `config.xml` to below code

```
<menu>

   <catalog>            
       <children>
           <items module="web">
               <title>Manage Items</title>
               <sort_order>0</sort_order>
               <action>web/adminhtml_web</action>    
           </items>
       </children>
    </catalog>

</menu>
```